# What is a Kafka broker? and how much resources of a PC does it take?

Tags: apache-kafka

Can a broker use only one core of my CPU so multiple brokers can reside in a single PC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A broker is the server process that responds to producer and consumer requests and hosts topic partition data.

Sure, multiple JVM of any Java process can be hosted on any supported machine. That's not unique to Kafka. You cannot directly control cores used by the JVM, AFAIK.

By default, the max heap space of Kafka is only 1G, but you may want additional overhead if you planning on running other Java based CLI tools it comes with, or Zookeeper on the same machine (not recommended).

Many people use Docker to run multiple brokers on one machine for testing, but this will not make it faster and is still a single point of failure